# Bar graphs with Single bar with data points (0,1) in c# chart controls

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I'm having a problem with chart controls in VS 3.5 framework . I'm trying plot a graph with x- axis 0 and y-axis 1. But it results with a graph plotted (1,1)

I have a situation where i need to have one single bar with (0,1).

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(0,1));
```

or

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(0,1);
```

Results:

> Bar graph (1,1) instead of showing (0,1) point

I have added

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[""].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
```

Still Showing the same result ...

This is so frustrating : When i add one more point (1,1)

Eg:

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(0,1);
Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1,1);
```

Then it results :

> bar graph with points (0,1) and (1,1) correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having this issue because the default series added to a chart is a bar graph. You will have to remove the bar graph series and replace it with a Point series in order to display your data. See sample code below.

```
// clear data from the chart
chart.Series.Clear();

// add an x-y series to the chart
var xySeries = new Charting.Series() {
    LegendText = "XY Plot",
    ChartType = Charting.SeriesChartType.Point,
    Color = Color.Brown,
    MarkerStyle = Charting.MarkerStyle.Circle,
    MarkerSize = 10
};
chart.Series.Add(xySeries);

// put your point on the series
xySeries.Points.AddXY(1, 1);

// set the axis
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dot;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dot;
```

This produces the following chart

[image: Chart Sample]

You will have to add this `using` statement to include `Charting` in the available namespaces.

```
using Charting = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

---

To change the labels on the X-Axis, you will have to use the `AxisLabel` property of the DataPoint. See sample below:

```
// put your point on the series
xySeries.Points.AddXY(0, 1);
xySeries.Points[0].AxisLabel = "0"; // <--- SET AXIS LABEL HERE
```

Doing will 'coerce' the Chart control to display your chosen axis label.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply . But I would like to go with Bar Graph.  Bar graph is my requirement. Is there any way , we can plot Point (0,1) in Bar graph???

Comment: Thanks again , Yeah .. I did the same thing and moving forward ... But it is so weird about the bar graph in Visual studio ...why dont the XYcoordinate values gives the correct results...